# Why can't I use "String" as a parameter for a priority queue?

Tags: java, class, processing, priority-queue

I'm trying to implement the A* algorithm in Processing 3, and I decided to use a priority grid to store and prioritize explorable nodes. I had just decided to do a simple test to make sure I knew the syntax, but when I try to set the type of the queue to "String" or "Integer" I get the error `The type filename.PriorityQueue is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>` Any idea why this is happening?

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Test {
    public void main(String[] args) {
      PriorityQueue<String> pq= new PriorityQueue<String>(5,(a,b) -> a.length() - b.length());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update your question to reflect the exact error code, as your error message strongly suggests that either you didn't copy it exactly or this isn't the actual code.

Comment: Please update your full source code. This error message means that you have another PriorityQueue class in your source. I think.

Comment: Please don't update the title with "\*Solved\*". Click the checkmark next to the answer that *best* answers the question to **accept** that as *the* answer to your question. You should also click the up-arrow next to *all* the answers you found to be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you have a file called `filename.java` that has a type called `PriorityQueue` that does not take generics. You should most likely delete that file and then import the PriorityQueue you want:

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
```

Comment: Sorry, I had formatted my post wrong. I had in fact added that, and "filename.java" is just the file this code is in.

Comment: @TaoGroves Since the class is named `Test` and is `public`, the source file name must be `Test.java`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you imported priority queue from java.util?
if not then:

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I was incredibly dumb and had accidentally made a PriorityQueue file in the same folder. Thanks for the quick answers.